# EpubReaderFragment.onCreate java.lang.IllegalStateException - Required value was null

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently using version 2.2.1 of readium (https://github.com/readium/kotlin-toolkit/blob/2.2.1/test-app/src/main/java/org/readium/r2/testapp/reader/EpubReaderFragment.kt).

I've encountered an issue reported by Crashlytics.

The error, a java.lang.IllegalStateException, specifically states: "Required value was null." The problem seems to be occurring in the reader.EpubReaderFragment.onCreate method at line 84.

Interestingly, this issue is not consistent across all devices. It occurs on some devices but not on others, even though they share the same model and Android version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have attached code snippets of where Crashlytics has reported the issue.

EpubReaderFragment.kt
[on create method code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3MCC.png)
ePubReaderFragment

issue happen on around 10% of devices not all and device that has issue once installed debug version to check it is working well.

I couldn't find a way to debug, I would appreciate advice from anyone who has like this issue